# How to get recommendations based on previous orders in neo4j?

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to work on neo4j for the first time. I have written the following:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///restaurant_data.csv" AS data
MERGE(n1:Customer{Name:data.Name, Latitude:toFloat(data.Latitude),Longitude:toFloat(data.Longitude)})
MERGE(n2:Orders{OrderId:data.Order_ID,OrderTimestamp:data.Order_ts,FoodName:data.Food_Item})
MERGE(n3:Restaurant{RestaurantName:data.Restaurant, RestLat:toFloat(data.Rest_lat), RestLong:toFloat(data.Rest_long)})
MERGE (n1)-[r1:PLACES_ORDER]->(n2)
MERGE (n2)-[r2:BELONGS_TO]->(n3)
MERGE (n3)-[r3:SERVES]->(n2)
RETURN *;
```

i can share the csv if needed.

I want to find recommendation of restaurant for customer based on his top 5 previous orders by order_timestamp and distance between restaurant and customer should be less than 5 kms.

```
MATCH(n1:Customer{Name:"Angy"})
MATCH(n1)-[:PLACES_ORDER]->(n2:Orders)<-[:SERVES]-(rec:Restaurant)
RETURN n2.FoodName, n2.OrderTimestamp, n3.RestaurantName
ORDER BY n2.OrderTimestamp
LIMIT 5
```

This gives me only top 5 orders, how do I find restaurants serving those orders?

My file link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTc35TBanV3Uk5gbCeEFeJkm2YAhbJPLnpS0KzmYErVRulvbXCWdSZ7xiKUfnCZQQUt-1ArabgmAGmL/pubhtml

Answer (score 0):

Your query did not work. This worked:

```
MATCH(:Customer{Name:"Angy"})-[:PLACES_ORDER]->(o:Orders) 
WITH o ORDER BY o.OrderTimestamp DESC LIMIT 5 
WITH [o.FoodName] as foods 
MATCH (r:Restaurant)-[:SERVES]->(n:Orders) 
WHERE (n.FoodName in foods) 
RETURN distinct r.RestaurantName,foods
```