# Cypher query returning no matches no records in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am building a reccomendation search query in cypher
I have produced the following:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///restaurant_data.csv" AS data
MERGE(n1:Customer{Name:data.Name, Latitude:toFloat(data.Latitude),Longitude:toFloat(data.Longitude)})
MERGE(n2:Orders{OrderId:data.Order_ID,OrderTimestamp:data.Order_ts,FoodName:data.Food_Item})
MERGE(n3:Restaurant{RestaurantName:data.Restaurant, RestLat:toFloat(data.Rest_lat), RestLong:toFloat(data.Rest_long)})
MERGE (n1)-[r1:PLACES_ORDER]->(n2)
MERGE (n2)-[r2:BELONGS_TO]->(n3)
MERGE (n3)-[r3:SERVES]->(n2)
RETURN *;


MATCH(n1:Customer{Name:"Angy"})-[:PLACES_ORDER]->(n2:Orders)<-[:SERVES]-(r:Restaurant)
WITH n2 ORDER BY n2.OrderTimestamp DESC LIMIT 5 
WITH collect(distinct n2) as orders
MATCH (r:Restaurant) WHERE ALL(order in orders WHERE EXISTS((r)-[:SERVES]->(order)))
RETURN DISTINCT r.RestaurantName
```

I want to find the last 5 orders of ANGY and give her recommendations of restaurants serving that order. However the above query returns `no matches no records`
Where am I going wrong? Please help!!! I AM NEW TO NEO4J

Comment: Does the import works? Does `MATCH (n) RETURN n LIMIT 10` returns anything?

Comment: no nothing. is my relationship making wrong here? i dont understand.

Comment: I can share u the csv file if needed.

Comment: Yes import is working. i do get my orders when i RETURN orders in my query

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get recommendations based on previous orders in neo4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71025499/how-to-get-recommendations-based-on-previous-orders-in-neo4j)

Answer (score 0):

```
MATCH(:Customer{Name:"Angy"})-[:PLACES_ORDER]->(o:Orders) 
WITH o ORDER BY o.OrderTimestamp DESC LIMIT 5 
WITH [o.FoodName] as foods 
MATCH (r:Restaurant)-[:SERVES]->(n:Orders) 
WHERE (n.FoodName in foods) 
RETURN distinct r.RestaurantName,foods
```

Finnally this worked for me.